# Get button clicked ID in "OnSuccess" function after form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

I am Using Ajax form in mvc3.

Below is code.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Method", "Conroller", new AjaxOptions
{
   UpdateTargetId = "PopupBody",
   HttpMethod = "post",
   OnSuccess = "OnSuccessContactInfoSave"
}, new { @id = "frmContactInfo" }))
{ %>



function OnSuccessContactInfoSave( data, textStatus ) {

alert( 'completed with success.' );
 }
```

Now, i have 2 buttons on a page one is submit button and another is normal button. 
Now, i want to know the clicked button in Onsuccess function .

How can i get it in "OnSuccessContactInfoSave" function?

Thanks in Advance

---

Edited :

This is My View

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveContactInfo", "ManageUser", new AjaxOptions
{
   UpdateTargetId = "PopupBody",
   HttpMethod = "Post"
}))
{ %> <div class="ciMain">

         <input type="submit" id="btnSaveAndClose" name="btn"  value="Save"   />
        <input type="submit" value="Save and continue to next step" name="btn" />
        <input type="button" value="Cancel"  />
      </div>
  <% } %>
```

This is Controller

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SaveContactInfo(FormCollection userViewModel, ContactInfoViewModel model, string btn)
    {
        //string test = Request["btn"].ToString();
        try
        {

            return View("ContactInfo", model);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("ContactInfo", model);
        }

    }
```

Comment: i tried with this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14980550/1752787

Comment: But, getting Request["btn"] == null , in this line :  Response.AppendHeader("X-Button", Request["btn"]);

Comment: AM i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a property with the name SubmissionType in the model class
ContactInfoViewModel like this:

```
public class ContactInfoViewModel
{
    public string SubmissionType { get; set; }
    //Your rest of properties
}
```

Now in your view pass this property name in your submit button something like this:

```
    <input type="submit" name="SubmissionType" id="btnSumit" value="Submit"/>
    <input type="submit" name="SubmissionType" id="btnOther" value="Other"/>
```

**Remember these buttons must be under form tag and also dont forget to bind your model with the view something like this:**

```
    @model ClassNamespace.ContactInfoViewModel
```

now you have to restructure your action method like this:

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SaveContactInfo(ContactInfoViewModel model)
    {          
        if (model.SubmissionType == "Submit")
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
        try
        {

            return View("ContactInfo", model);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("ContactInfo", model);
        }
    }
```

Now coming to your ajax form tag, you also have to pass **Model** here so that you can get the values of your model at the time of form submission. Do it like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveContactInfo", "ManageUser",Model, new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "PopupBody",
HttpMethod = "Post"
}))
```

As you can see in the above code I have also passed model as **object routeValues**.

Hope now this will solve your problem.